# JQuery To Only Add Checked Rows To Array

Tags: jquery, asp.net, arrays, gridview, webforms

I am attempting to only add `asp:gridviews` that have been checked to my JQuery array.  My issue with this is that all rows are added, regardless of check status.

What would be the proper way to only add checked rows to this array:

```
<script>
    $("#btnTest").click(function () {
        var AjaxData = {};
        var AjaxDataList = [];
        var grids = ["gridGreen", "GridRed""];
        var gridlen = grids.length;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < gridlen; i++) {
            $('[id*=' + grids[i] + ']').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
        var gridrow = $(this);
        var colno = 2;
            $('#checkboxtest input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    AjaxData.fldPresenting = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                }
            }
        });
        AjaxDataList.push(AjaxData);
        Console.Log(AjaxDataList);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fill the array inside of the `checked` condition.

```
$("#btnTest").click(function () {
    //var AjaxData = {};
    var AjaxDataList = [];
    var grids = ["gridGreen", "GridRed"];
    var gridlen = grids.length;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < gridlen; i++) {
        $('[id*=' + grids[i] + ']').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
        $('#checkboxtest input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                //AjaxData.fldPresenting = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                AjaxDataList.push($(this).attr("id"));//Push the checked checkbox
            }
        }
    });
    Console.Log(AjaxDataList);
    }
});
```

Also, I couldn't understand the `AjaxData` purpose and there is no declaration for `gridrow` and `colno` variables in your code snippet.

Comment: Doesn't make sense looping all checkboxes inside another loop

Comment: Am I not filling the array inside the for loop?  If I look at the closing } for the for loop AjaxDataList.Push(AjaxData) is inside the closing bracket

Comment: @charlietfl - alternate suggestion?

Comment: @Smith, I mean you should fill the array in the checked condition. Otherwise you push the all checkboxes to array.

Comment: @SmithStanley not really clear what the grids are for and why you loop them in the first place

Comment: @Stormcloak - I move my insert statement inside the checked condition, but everything is still pushed.

Comment: Is the $(this) referencing #checkboxtest or the actual row of the asp:gridview?

Comment: It should reference the checkbox.